# Proof of induction principle, Proof falsification

Tags: logic, induction

I just had a very frustating conversation with one of my Professors. I'm tutoring for a lecture course on Analysis and in the lecture he gave a proof of the induction principle. I was trying to tell him that it is not correct because it is cyclic, but he doesn't see my point. So the argument is as follows:

**Theorem.** Assume that

1. $\varphi(1)$ is true
2. $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : (\varphi(n)\rightarrow \varphi(n+1))$

then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : \varphi(n)$

**Proof.** Assume there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\neg\varphi(k)$. We do know at this point that there is a predecessor-chain of lenght k resulting in $1$, i.e. there are $c_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for $1\leq i\leq k$ s.t. $c_{i+1}=c_i+1, c_1=1$ and $c_k=k$.

Now by assumption we have $\neg\varphi(c_k) \stackrel{2)}{\Rightarrow}\neg\varphi(c_{k-1}) \stackrel{2)}{\Rightarrow}\dots \stackrel{2)}{\Rightarrow}\neg\varphi(c_1)$ contradicting 1).

Now I claim that to formaly proof the "$\dots$" part, we already implicitly use the induction principle, because we use the fact that the property $\neg\varphi$
 inherits down along arbitrary long predecessor chains, ie. we need the statement:

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$: If $c_i\in\mathbb{N}$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ s.t. $c_{i+1}=c_i+1$ and $\neg\varphi(c_n)$ then $\neg\varphi(c_1)$.

And this Statement can only be proved by induction.

He claimed, that we do not need this statement, because we pick a fixed $k$ and $k$ is finite, so we only have to go down a finite number of times.

However I insist that one does need it, since while its clearly true that one only has to go down a finite number of times, this number could be an arbitrary large finite number, since of course $k$ can be arbitrary large, therefore we have to proof the downward transfer for arbitrary long predecessor chains and hence need above statement.

I don't know what more I could say to convince him.

**Edit**: **Definition.** $\mathbb{N}$ is a set s.t.

1. $1\in\mathbb{N}$
2. There exists a injective function $\Phi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with $\forall n : \Phi(n)\neq 1$
3. If $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and A satisfies 1) and 2) then $A=\mathbb{N}$

For readability I also write $n+1$ for $\Phi(n)$ above.

Comment: We must show the set that contains the numbers for which the statement is true, is inductive. I'm not sure what kind of basis of definitions you have, but in our analysis course, proof of induction principle was proved using the inductive subset definition

Comment: You are right. Indeed, the induction principle is part of the definition of $\Bbb{N}$, hence it does not make any senso to prove it.

Comment: Yes, I know how to prove it properly, I'm just looking for an argument why above proof is not correct. @AlvinLepik

Comment: "this number could be an arbitrary large finite number, since of course $k$ can be arbitrary large" I'd say this is not true, as $k$ is fixed at the beginning of the proof.

Comment: I'm not seeing how, if there is such a $k$ for which the statement is false, it follows that all the previous ones are also false.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Assume $\phi(k-1)$ is true. Then by (2), we infer $\phi(k-1+1)=\phi(k)$, contradiction. Therefore $\phi(k-1)$ is false

Comment: @KevinQuirin k could be arbitrary large, because we don't know where the first counterexample occurs, if one exists

Comment: @Sebastian We are proving "$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$" by contradiction and therefore we start with "Suppose $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\phi(k)$ is false". Inside of the proof we are supposing that there exists a $k$ that works as a counterexample

Comment: Right, but we do not know anything other about k apart from $\neg\varphi(k)$

Comment: @Sebastian Yes we know, that's exactly what we supposed.

Comment: We only supposed $\neg\varphi(k)$. Nothing more about k.

Comment: We are assuming that for any natural number k that the chain k-1, k-2,... will eventually reach 1.  Which I don't see how is any more or less justified than assuming the chain 1,2,3, ... etc. will hit every natural number.   The argument "k is finite so we go down a finite number of times" sounds no more or less valid the "n is finite so we only go up an finite number of times".

Comment: @fleablood I also was telling him exactly that also. :-/

Comment: I'm out of my area and I doubt I could axiomatically define the Natural numbers (your definition passes the scanning during bout of insomnia test) but it really does seem that what ever axiom allows us to count the natural numbers is equivalent to and directly implies the induction process.

Comment: Hmm... he *might* be right (though I doubt it).  What is the definition of "finite"?  If finite means "reachable by counting" he is right.  But then so would be saying as all "n are finite; the result can be reached by iterating a finite number of times for every finite number".  Wouldn't it?  It's circular all the way down... or up.

Comment: @MorganRodgers  Well *we* don't do the counting.  This is semantic handwaving but if instead of saying "for all n" we say "for any arbitrary finite n" we avoid/solve the issue with equal (none or all) validity.  ... but it is a valid question.  Can we assume if it's true for an arbitrary value then it is true for all?  If not, can an arbitrary counterexample's impossibility prove for all.  If so, your professor might have a point.  But if so the subtlety of the nescesity of a finite counterexample doesn't fit the informality of the proof.

Comment: @MorganRodgers You said it was better to count down from one k then to count up through all n forever.  I don't think that matters.  We only need to count up to one finite n. Then as n is arbitrary (as arbitrary as the k) we have shown it is true "for any arbitrary finite n" which is semantically the same as "for all n".   *BUT* as axiomatic logic is precise I'm willing to consider that *maybe* we can't make the single arbitrary => all assumption.  but *maybe* not(not(single arbitrary)) => all is okay.  If so, maybe the professor is right.  *Maybe*.

Comment: @fleablood You need to show it is true for **every** choice of an arbitrary $n$. Not just for **some** arbitrary $n$. That's why contradiction is the preferred method.  While there might not be a problem with counting up, I think it's a little more hand-wavey.  And I don't think there's anything technically wrong with the professor's solution.

Comment: @MorganRodgers but don't you have to prove that you can count down from every k?  And what if the counterexample didn't happen at k but at m, or j? Do we have to show we can count down from all n.  Okay, start from one and count up.. hey do I know that I'll hit k.  Because if I start at k and go down I have to hit one. How do I know that?  Well, because k is finite I can only do this k times before I hit 0.  Okay, but if I count up I can only go k times before I go above k.  Either I know both hit their targets or I don't know either hit their target.  Both are self-evident or both are cyclic.

Comment: The arbitrary $\ne$ every argument may have merit though.  I'm not ruling it out.  And it's possible that not(not(some)) => every. But if so I'd say that from that we can prove arbitrary => every because not(some) => not(arbitrary).  Maybe the professor *is* right but if so s/he really needs to explicitly state the precise axioms that make counting down not circular.  Because either induction is "self-evident" or it is excedingly subtle.  If excedingly subtle the proof must reflect that which this one doesn't.

Comment: Hmm.... beginning more and more to see the professor's point.  Can we claim that addition and subtraction is defined and that k -> k-1 iterated k-1 time is k-(k-1) = 1?  That would mean -phi(k) => -phi(1) via a finite number of iterations.  However shouldn't this mean for any finite n phi(1) => phi(n) and there for we can not pick a n where  -phi(n) so phi(n) for all n... which I guess *is* the professors proof.  I've changed my mind and think the professor is correct *IF* we are allowed to know subtraction is well defined.

Answer (score 2):

$\dots$ is not a mathematical operator.  If your prof thinks his proof is correct, then he should be able to write it without $\dots$ .  When $\dots$ is used correctly, it is simply tedious to replace it with symbolic logic.  In the above case, it is impossible to replace it with symbolic logic so the professors proof is wrong.

Many attempts at proofs of induction can be disregarded due to a simple transform:  instead of considering the natural numbers $\mathbb N$, consider the set of polynomials with natural number coefficients, $\mathbb N [x]$.  $\mathbb N [x]$ shares most properties of natural numbers, such as being injective (wrt adding one) and having a zero.  It is also totally well ordered.  However, it is not an inductive set.   So any "proof" of induction that doesn't make an assumption true of $\mathbb N$ but not $\mathbb N[x]$ is wrong.

Comment: He uses the phrase "We do know at this point", so presumably it isn't an assumption.  Unless he has some amazingly new and unique framework of logic, it isn't even a mathematical statement, any moreso than "100 is a really big number", it just uses a lot of words from mathematics.   What assumptions did he use to arrive at that point, and which one doesn't apply to natural numbers?  What rules of inference did he use?  I suspect not much more than "well I know it intuitively".

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in his statement "go down a finite number of times". This statement is informal and does not in it self show anything. In order to use this statement and expound on it he would actually have to show that he may do this for $k=1$, $k=2$, $k=3$, etc. or if he do not wish do do an infinite algorithm, he may use induction.

Comment: That's what I was telling him.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thought and back and forth in the comments, I decided that your professor is probably right.

I'm assuming pre-induction we are allowed to do any number of finite iterations:

So if:

1)True for $n =1$

2)If true for $n$ then true for $n +1$

Then we can conclude:

3) True for $k$ after $k - 1$ iterations.

But that's all.  We can't conclude that it is true for all $n$ simply because we can show it is true for arbitrary $n$.  arbitrary $\not \implies$ every....yet.

If, however, we assume 2) and 1) and that it is not true for a finite $k$ then we can show it is not true for $k - 1$.

We can re-iterate this $k -1$ times and conclude it is not true for $n = 1$ which is a contradiction.  So there is no $k$ that this is not true for.  Hence it is true for all $n$.

The subtle but crucial difference between these two methods, is that $k$ was not an arbitrary number, and the number of iterations to get to $n = 1$ was finite, precise and determined.

And it only takes one counter example to disprove a universal statement, but it takes an infinite multitude to prove it directly.  (Unless we can prove arbitrary $\implies$  every which I think we can... maybe.)

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't say that he's necessarily wrong, but it's a questionable approach. There **could** be a hidden circular reasoning buried in the details, but basically without the proof of the details you cannot say.

The definition of $\mathbb N$ basically already contains the induction principle in the third requirement. Let $A=\{x\in\mathbb N: \phi(x)\}$ one could easily see that this is a subset of $\mathbb N$ that fulfills the first and second requirements and therefor according to the third requirement we have $A=\mathbb N$, therefore $\phi(x)$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb N$. This shows that basically anything provable with the induction principle can be proved using the third requirement instead (so anything you say is proved by using the induction principle could have been proven without it).

It's not just the $\cdots$ part that's problematic in his proof, also the fact that there's a predecessor chain at all, the fact that it would terminate at $1$ need to be proven first too. Any these proofs that are prerequisite of the proof of the induction principle **could** have used induction principle itself (but could have been shown using the third requirement instead). Even if it's not wrong to do so one would question why one would produce a lot of proofs that begs for the induction principle in order to prove the induction principle when it was readily provable directly instead (it's like a mathematical Rube Goldstein Machine).

Actually you will have to use the third requirement to end up with the induction principle anyway (so you can not use that as an excuse - that you're using a more complicated proof to get rid of one prerequisite).
If you drop the last statement you'll end up in a definition from which you can't prove the induction principle. To see this one could for example construct a set that fulfills the Peano's axiom except the induction principle that it doesn't: for example just extend $\mathbb N$ with a new element $\infty = \Phi(\infty)$. We see that the first two requirements are met, but not the third - in this set we can easily see that induction principle doesn't work as we could for example consider $\phi(x): x\in\mathbb N$.

One detail about that formulation of the induction principle is that it's a statement about an arbitrary statement. Formally this isn't allowed and therefore it should be considered what's called a theorem schema. This means that for each statement $\phi$ you can substitute that into the schema and get a valid theorem instance.

A proof of such a schema is not the same as a proof in the formal sense as it's more of a recipe of how to prove any theorem instance. As such the proof schema itself need not be formally verifiable as long as each instantiation of it is. Now if there's a concrete counter example we would have a $\phi$ and $k$ and expanding the proof schema would actually result in a formally valid proof.